# How can I connect to a iPhone web application using Perl?

Tags: iphone, perl, lwp

Is it possible to use Perl's LWP from my Windows PC to scrape contents of iPhone web application? If yes, which parameters I should change or could someone provide example?

Answer (score 0):

No, web applications running on the iPhone are run inside of the browser.  LWP lets you connect to web **servers**, not web **browsers**.  That said, where are you getting the web application?  You may be able to run it directly in Perl using [`WWW::HTMLUnit`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aHtmlUnit).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the web application, but you probably won't be able to do anything with it in Perl because most of the fun stuff happens with Javascript. However, you might be able to extract various data, links, and so on.

To see what your phone is sending to websites, write a little CGI program to dump it's input and environment. You'll especially be interested in the user-agent string. Through [LWP::UserAgent](https://www.metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent), you can set any of those values yourself.

Comment: There are JavaScript engines in Perl now.  `WWW::HTMLUnit`, `WWW::Scripter`, and possibly others.